Setting up HP Printer software (hplip) for scanning in a docker container
Recently I updated my server from ubuntu 22 LTS to 24 LTS (Server). Turns out that HP didn't release a hplip software that's capable of dealing with ubuntu 24 yet.
Via this server I used the my HP All-in-one printer only for convenient scanning, triggered by the home automation, so I just need the scanning functionality.
So now as the hplip software obviously doesn't work on ubuntu 24 at all, I had the idea about setting all the hplip stuff up in a docker container, based on ubuntu:22 or fedora:41 (<- which seems to have the most recent hplip version).
However I didn't succeed yet, receiving different errors on every try.
Anybody here who managed to set up hplip in a docker container?
Or do you have any other idea how to get it running except downgrading to ubuntu 22?
(I am quite experienced in docker and a bit in linux server administration, but not at all in printers/scanners on linux)
